# Error Foregin key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un create table y tengo dos constraints pero em da un error:

```
CREATE TABLE score (
score_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
race_id int(11) NOT NULL,
modality_id int(11) NOT NULL,
header longtext,
PRIMARY KEY (score_id),
FOREIGN KEY (race_id) REFERENCES race(race_id),
FOREIGN KEY (modality_id) REFERENCES modality(modality_id)
);
```

> 1005 - No puedo crear tabla `score` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Las otras tablas ya estan creadas.

Comment: La sotras tablas que hago referencia ya estan creadas pero esta no me deja

Answer (score 1):

Te falta un `REFERENCES`

```
CREATE TABLE score (
    score_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    race_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    modality_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    header longtext,
    PRIMARY KEY (score_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (race_id) REFERENCES race(race_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (modality_id) REFERENCES modality(modality_id)
);
```

Comment: Si tienes razon, lo tengo puesto no se porque no me salio aqui. Me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Coinciden el tipo de dato referenciado con el referenciante? ¿El referenciante incluye toda la clave del referenciado?

Comment: Tendria que coincidir race_id int(11) not null y modality_id int(11) not null ?

Comment: De que tipo es el dato race_id de la tabla race?

Comment: int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 0):

Saludos puedes intentar lo siguiente teniendo como ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE padre (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE hija (
    id INT,
    padre_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (padre_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (padre_id) REFERENCES padre(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Si te fijas también agrega "**ENGINE=INNODB**"

para mayor información te sugiero revisar la documentación: [Foreign Key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)